# Connect to internal GCP host from local host using one command

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

So, I have my local host computer (let it be Z.Z.Z.Z) and I configured two hosts on Google Cloud Platform. One host has static public IP (let it be X.X.X.X) and one host has ephemeral IP (let it be Y.Y.Y.Y). Now I can ssh to my host with public IP. I do it like so:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/testuser -A @testuser@X.X.X.X
```

I see a nice prompt and it's all ok. I can now ssh from this host to internal host. I do it like so:

```
X.X.X.X:~$ ssh Y.Y.Y.Y
```

And again it's all ok - I see a nice prompt of my second internal host. What I want to achieve is to be able to ssh from my localhost (Z.Z.Z.Z) right to my internal host on GCP. I guess, I need something like port forwarding or something like that. I tried a lot of solutions from SO, but what I get is `Permission denied`. So, what I need are those exact commands that will be able to implement my task.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using your host with the static public IP x.x.x.x as a bastion host.  there is a good article here about that topic
https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/11/21/using-ssh-bastion-host/

The other issue might be VPC connection related if your 2 hosts inside of GCP are on different VPC's.  Routing and firewalls can come into play when going between VPCs as you would probably expect.
Since you are initiating access inbound, I'm not sure if egress rules are needed or if the implied egress rule is sufficient.  That could come into play as well: 
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules

From a troubleshooting standpoint you can oalso use https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs

Comment: Welcome to Super User. On this Q&A site we value answers that stand on their own. Hyperlinks alone point toward an answer [without actually being one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please [edit] your answer so that it includes the essential elements from your linked source.